# Installs on Facebook Analytics differ from iTunes Connect and Google Play

Tags: android, ios, google-play, app-store-connect, facebook-analytics

I'm measuring the number of installs for my application, on both iOS and Android, through Facebook Analytics. This has been setup with Facebook SDK to enable install tracking. It seems to be working fine and I'm able to follow the number of installs.

My problem is that when I look at the number of installs I get from iTunes Connect (App Units) and Google Play (Total Installs), they don't match the numbers from Facebook Analytics. Both iTunes Connect and Google Play register on average 15% more installs than Facebook Analytics. Can anyone help me to get an understanding of why this is happening and what I can do about it? If not, which of these numbers are more reliable?

Thank you for your time and your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

App Units on iTunes Connect App Analytics are the actual "purchases"/downloads. Bus some users might never even open your app. That's why it's possible that App Units might be higher than the numbers from Facebook. I assume at least for iOS that Facebook can only send information on the first launch of the app, not on the actual install.

Comment: You are correct. [This link](https://www.facebook.com/help/analytics/1630548303851501) was for some reason unexpectedly difficult to find but it states that "App Installs (Installs): The number of unique people that launched your app for the first time within a given time period."

Answer (score -1):

Facebook Analytics for installation are not real time, some time they reflect on backend within 1 hour.

Apps are though installed, though counts are getting reflected on iTunes and but when user open app then only that count gets reflect on Facebook / Google analytics.

Comment: Facebook Analytics for Apps is near real-time and will typically show an install within ~2 minutes from any event being sent, including install.